# How do I capture the distribution of a discrete random variable signal in a mixture model?

Tags: optimization, hidden-markov-model, mixture-distribution

A signal of unknown length with observations [0,1,2,3] is found in a lengthier chain of values. There is some uniform distribution for noise in the background that is known, however the probability distribution for the signal of unknown length is specific to its index in the signal.

For instance, a signal might be:

```
               probability of observation   
              0        1         2        3
pos 0:      25%,       0%,      75%,      0%
pos 1:     100%,       0%,       0%,      0%
pos 2:      25%,      25%,      25%,     25%
...
pos n:
```

While the background here does not have positional indexes and is uniformly

```
bg:         25%,      25%,      25%,     25%
```

And the data (said 'lengthier chains') would be found in the form of

```
0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, ...
```

So to reiterate, the background distribution is known and I am trying to determine 1) length of the signal and 2) the distribution of each position signal. There are many of these lengthier chains each containing an instance of signal, from which we find some sort of minimum-loss solution describing the best distribution for the signal. In more elaborate cases, there are multiple different signals and no guarantee of the occurrences of these signals in the lengthier chains.

I was thinking perhaps a HMM would be fitting given that we are trying to find the signal amidst a known background distribution (bg state, signal pos 0 state, signal pos 1 state, etc), but I do not know how I would develop the model because the signal is of unknown length and thus the number of hidden states is unknown.

How should I approach this problem? I'm having difficulty looking into this more because I can't find the key words to describe it, and would be grateful for any information also that leads to further reading.

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to understand the question. Could you please try to clarify your first two paragraphs? More details of your specific problem might help.

Comment: Sure I will try to better describe the data

Comment: Alright, I have added a table and some other additional information that hopefully helps clarify the problem and represent the data.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are trying to classify signals: noise versus signal or if you are trying to determine the distribution fitting the signal best.
In the first case, you could use an HMM modeling the noise and consider everything that deviates from this model as a signal (though if the noise is a simple white noise, there must be more straightforward methods). In the latter case, the HMM will be of no help as the distribution type has to be decided before training any HMM (the training equations change depending of the distribution type). So please, precise your question.

Comment: Sorry, for clarification I wish to find the distribution that best fits the signal. By distribution type do you mean the form of the distribution for which I can find parameters? I was thinking I could do model selection over a preset range of signal lengths using BIC after finding EM solutions for each signal length, but it seems clunky and tedious. How else might I find the distribution type?